# Product Line Item Varient Schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My end goal here is when an admin creates a product, they can choose which variants are available for selection by the end user when adding to cart, sometimes multiple choices, sometimes only one choice. For example, one size only, small, medium, etc.

Here's my product schema:

```
schema "products" do
  field :category, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :image, Qcrafts.Images.Type
  field :name, :string
  field :price, :decimal
  field :slug, ProductSlug.Type

  timestamps()
end
```

And my `line_item`:

```
embedded_schema do
  field :product_id, :integer
  field :image, Qcrafts.Images.Type
  field :product_name, :string
  field :quantity, :integer
  field :unit_price, :decimal
  field :total, :decimal
  field :delete, :boolean, virtual: true
end
```

Which relationships do I need that suits best and whats the best way to handle it on the template?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your stuff much, I think I would do something like this:

```elixir
defmodule Product do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "products" do
    field :category, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :slug, ProductSlug.Type
    has_many :variants, ProductVariant
    belongs_to :default_variant, ProductVariant

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

```elixir
defmodule ProductVariant do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "product_variants" do
    field :product_id, :id
    field :description, :string
    field :image, Qcrafts.Images.Type
    field :name, :string
    field :price, :decimal
    field :slug, ProductSlug.Type

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

```elixir
defmodule LineItem do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :product_variant_id, :id
    field :image, Qcrafts.Images.Type
    field :product_name, :string
    field :quantity, :integer
    field :unit_price, :decimal
    field :total, :decimal
    field :delete, :boolean, virtual: true
  end
end
```

In a template you could do something like: (make sure you preload)

form example:

```
multiple_select(form, :variants, Enum.map(@product.variants, &({&1.name, &1.id})),
                selected: Enum.map(@product.variants, &(&1.id)))
```

or list example:

```elixir
<ul>
  <%= for variant <- @product.variants do %>
    <li><%= variant.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```